# RecyclerView work with localhost but dont show items with online server

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hi everyone My problem is weird. I have an app that works with volley and mysql. When I launch the app using xampp it works fine. The list is saved in the adapter and adapter works well in the recycler view. But when I change the url to my mysql database hosted on my website, the recycler view does not show the data. The JSON data is correctly received and saved correctly in the Arraylist (check it with Toast messages). I have the same problem in real devices
Android Studio will not throw me any error or warning running

**Rubros**

```
public class Rubros {
    String nombre;
    String rubro_id;

    public Rubros(String nombre, String rubro_id) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.rubro_id = rubro_id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getRubro_id() {
        return rubro_id;
    }

    public void setRubro_id(String rubro_id) {
        this.rubro_id = rubro_id;
    }
}
```

**ListaRubros.class**

```
public class ListaRubros extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView rv_rubros;
RubroAdapter adapter;
List <Rubros> listarubros;
String categoria;
String categoria_id;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista_rubros);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    //Buscamos la categoria
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    categoria = bundle.getString("categoria");
    setTitle(categoria);
    categoria_id = bundle.getString("categoria_id");

    //Declaramos variable textview
    listarubros= new ArrayList<>();
    //cargamos la lista de rubros
    rv_rubros = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_rubros);
    //Preparamos el adapter
    rv_rubros.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    rv_rubros.setLayoutManager(llm);
    //guardamos la lista en adapter
    cargarRubros(categoria_id);
    adapter = new RubroAdapter(listarubros);
    rv_rubros.setAdapter(adapter);
    //agregamos el onClick Listener
    adapter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String rubro=listarubros.get(rv_rubros.getChildAdapterPosition(view)).getNombre();
            String rubro_id=listarubros.get(rv_rubros.getChildAdapterPosition(view)).getRubro_id();
            Intent intent = new Intent(ListaRubros.this,ListaNegocios.class);
            intent.putExtra("rubro",rubro);
            intent.putExtra("rubro_id",rubro_id);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

public void cargarRubros(String categoria){

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url ="http://10.0.3.2/listin/plantilla/sql/vistarubros_categoria_id.php?cc="+categoria; //Creamos la url

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                response = response.replace("][",",");


                if (response.length()>0){
                    try {
                        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(response);
                        for(int i=0;i<ja.length();i+=2){
                            try {
                                Rubros rubro = new Rubros(ja.getString(i),ja.getString(i+1));
                                listarubros.add(rubro);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),listarubros.get(0).getNombre(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
    queue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

}

**RubrosAdapter**

```
public class RubroAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RubroAdapter.DatosRubroViewHolder>
    implements View.OnClickListener{

List<Rubros> listarubros;
private View.OnClickListener listener;

public RubroAdapter(List<Rubros> listarubros) {
    this.listarubros = listarubros;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RubroAdapter.DatosRubroViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.vista_rv_rubros,parent,false);
    v.setOnClickListener(this);
    DatosRubroViewHolder holder = new DatosRubroViewHolder(v);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RubroAdapter.DatosRubroViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.rubro.setText(listarubros.get(position).getNombre());
    holder.rubro_id.setText(listarubros.get(position).getRubro_id());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listarubros.size();
}

public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener){
    this.listener=listener;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(listener!=null){
        listener.onClick(view);
    }
}

public static class DatosRubroViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView rubro;
    TextView rubro_id;
    public DatosRubroViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        rubro = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_rubro);
        rubro_id = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_rubro_id);
    }
}
```

}

**EDIT**
I already solved the problem. I had forgotten to add adapter.notifyDataSetChanged (); after saving the data in the arraylist